# Xcode 画面サイズ取得コードの使い回し　CGSize sc = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Objective-cにて、下記のコードを都度書かずにすむ方法を教えてください。

`CGSize sc = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;`

端末の画面サイズを取得してレイアウトなどを行う際に、毎回記載を行っているのですが、どこに宣言すればよいのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score -1):

スクリーンサイズ依存のコードはオートレイアウトをしっかり書く事でスクリーンサイズの実ピクセル数が必要になるケースはかなり減らせると思いますが、オートレイアウトとは別にという前提で回答します。

`UIApplication`のサブクラスを作成し、`screenSize`というリードオンリーのプロパティを定義し、`init`時にscreenSizeを実行するのはいかがでしょうか？

サンプルコードは以下の様になります

[アプリケーション名].h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface [アプリケーション名] : UIApplication
@property(readonly) CGSize  screenSize;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

[アプリケーション名].m

```
#import "[アプリケーション名].h"

@implementation [アプリケーション名]
@synthesize screenSize;

- (nonnull instancetype) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

これを利用するためには、`info.plist`にアイテムを追加し、`principal class`を選び、右の欄に[アプリケーション名]を書きます。

あとは、`screenSize`を参照したいソースファイルに

```
#import "[アプリケーション名].h"
```

としておいてから、`screenSize`が必要な箇所で

```
CGSize screenSize = (([アプリケーション名] *)[UIApplication sharedApplication]).screenSize;
```

と、することでアプリケーション起動時に取得した`screenSize`が参照出来ます。

結局面倒くさいので、毎回書いてもそんなに変わらないと思いますが、参照する使い回したい変数(`readwrite`)や定数(`readonly`)が増えてくると案外有効なので参考になれば幸いです